# Is there a way in Excel to extract rows by column string value?

Tags: excel

Can someone help me with excel? I want to extract data by OU name to different sheets. I'm aware of using filters or using a text-to-column function, but for filters, it's just manual work which would love to automate, and for the text-to-column function it does not work as some of the rows have more parameters than others. Please see per example:

**Sheet 1** (Main)

Name | dn

A1  | CN=A1,OU=int,OU=Region1, DC=company,DC=com

A2  | CN=A2,OU=Ext,OU=AddiotionalInfo, OU=Region1,DC=company,DC=com

B1  | CN=B1,OU=int,OU=Region2,DC=company,DC=com

B2  | CN=B2,OU=ext, OU=Region3,DC=company,DC=com

C3  | CN=C3,OU=ext, OU=Region2,DC=company,DC=com

Is it possible to extract data to:

**Sheet 2** by OU=Region1

Name    | dn

A1  | CN=A1,OU=int,OU=Region1, DC=company,DC=com

A2  | CN=A2,OU=Ext,OU=AddiotionalInfo,OU=Region1,DC=company,DC=com

**Sheet 3** by OU=Region2

Name    | dn

B1  | CN=B1,OU=int,OU=Region2,DC=company,DC=com

C3  | CN=C3,OU=ext,OU=Region2,DC=company,DC=com

**Sheet 4** by OU=Region3

Name    | dn

B2  | CN=B2,OU=ext,OU=Region3,DC=company,DC=com

There are more regions to it so maybe there’s a formula in which it would be possible to enter “RegionX” and extract it to the second sheet?

I’m pretty new to excel and how to extract data so any resources would also be helpful. A lot of information provided on google regards the extraction of data by numbers, not by values.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```
=FILTER('Sheet 1'!A2:B6,ISNUMBER(FIND("OU=" & A1,'Sheet 1'!B2:B6)))
```

It assumes that the data are on `Sheet 1` and the region to be filtered for in `A1` of the target sheet.